# Django (1.7) is placing migrations in the wrong app

Tags: django

I have a project structure something like the following:

models.py:

```
project
    parentapp
        __init__.py
        models.py
        migrations
            __init__.py
        subapp1
            models.py
            migrations
                __init__.py
        subapp2
            models.py
            migrations
                __init__.py
    project
        __init__.py
        settings.py
```

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    ...
    'parentapp',
    'parentapp.subapp1',
    'parnetapp.subapp2',
)
```

Then I run

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

It places parentapp's migrations in `parentapp/migrations/` (as it should).
It places subapp1's migrations in `subapp1/migrations/` (as it should).
*However*, it places subapp2's migrations in *`parentapp/migrations/`*, rather than in `subapp2/migrations/`...

Even if I run `python manage.py makemigration subapp2`, it still places subapp2's migrations in the wrong folder.  Aside from just being weird, when Django does that, any attempts to create a model in the subapp2 app will fail with `ProgrammingError: relation "parentapp_somesubapp2model" does not exist"`.

To get around the problem for now, I can manually hack up a migration for subapp2, but, for future reference, and to avoid the problem in the future, **How does Django decide when the subapp's migrations should go in the parent app, and when they should go in the subapp folder?

Is there a way to force it one way or the other?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In settings, you can set the [MIGRATION_MODULES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#migration-modules) dictionary explicitly and pass in the correct location of an app's migrations:

```
MIGRATION_MODULES = {
 'subapp2': 'subapp2.migrations'
}
```